# React Native error- Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: react-native

I am getting following error which was working earlier perfectly but next day it start to throw this error.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Problems reading data from Binary store in C:\Users\wsguest\AppData\Local\Temp\gradle8528155178066901693.bin offset 38021 exists? true

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 14s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c react-native run-android

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\wsguest\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-05-18T00_30_03_793Z-debug.log
```

Any suggestion what could be reason for error?

Comment: Try to clear node_modules and gradle files and rebuild again.

```
rm -rf node_modules
cd android
./gradlew clean
cd ..
yarn
cd android
./gradlew assembleRelease
```